# How to fetch 2 fragments (1 is re-fetchable) sequentially

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am new to Relay and currently trying to build an address form that includes 2 drop-downs:

1. a list of countries
2. a list of states in the selected country

For simplicity the component can be like this

```
const AddressForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  // ... some logic to fetch from server

  return (
    <>
      <Countries country={country} onCountryChange={setCountry} />
      <br />
      <States state={state} onStateChange={setState} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Both lists are stored in our graphql server. The form can have an initial country value of `''`. Whenever the country value changes, we need to fetch the list of states for the newly selected country. When fetching the list of states I don't want the whole form to suspend, rather just the States component.

Following the Relay guidelines, I have the following assumptions:

1. The `Countries` component should declare a fragment that lists the fields of Country it needs, i.e. `name` and `code`
2. The States component should declare a re-fetchable fragment that lists the fields of States it needs, also `name` and `code`

I am struggling to find a guide on how to achieve this and facing these issues:

1. [useRefetchableFragment](https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/use-refetchable-fragment/) requires a fragment ref as the second argument. If I include the States fragment in the query of AddressForm then the whole AddressForm component suspends when the Country changes.
2. I suspect I need to make 2 queries in AddressForm (although not sure) and don't know how to achieve this in Relay

Any guidance is appreciated